# Pipe delimited SSRS report has additional line in the bottom when there is no data

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

The file rendered from SSRS designed report is showing an additional line in the bottom of the file with pipes. The file is just supposed to show header information with pipes, but additionally has a line with ||||| next line when there is no data. I worked on a different report before which didn't have this issue, so I compared all tablix properties between these two reports and there is no difference but when I click report preview and export in pipe delimited format, I see the issue. Looks like this is a know bug when excel mode is set to true, but in my case the format is pipe delimited text file.

Comment: Wont the pipe delimited file properties (settings in the config file) be the same as a CSV config file setting except the separator is a Pipe rather than a comma? In which case, excel mode might still be turned on in the setting? Check the config file

Comment: @Harry the previous report I was talking about is also on same server with exact same report properties (verified from designer), the older one doesn't have that additional line when there is no data and just shows header information. I'm missing something obvious perhaps ?

Comment: @Harry I was wrong. I actually found the solution myself, technically reports were in 'QA' servers for my testing but on two different versions.. so I checked the SQL server config file settings and found the difference, so I moved the report to another one and found it working perfectly fine. Thanks for your answer which at least has put me in right direction.